# How do I search by file extension in MacOS Finder?

Tags: finder, macos

In trying to search for a `.ai` file, I have tried doing `kind:ai`, and have also tried doing it via the kind selector (see image below). I know how to do this using the linux "find" command already, but I really want to find a way to do this using the native finder interface.

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

OK, I finally figured it out with the following approach:

1. Open finder to the top-level directory you wish to search
2. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
3. From the search menu options, on the left, choose `other`
4. Click the checkbox under the `In Menu` column for `file extension` from the popup window and close the popup window by pressing `OK`
5. Select `file extension` from the search menu
6. Type your file extension in the text field (follows the word `is`)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:
click Spotlight in the menu bar
type  .ai  in the search field.

Comment: The limit here is only finding some .ai files. When I click on "Show all in finder" it doesn't show me only .ai files.