# Finder.app : Sort by Extension

Tags: finder, sort

#### Question

How could I **Sort by Extension** in **Column View** (as a standard view, not as a search) using the Finder.app (*as opposed to an [alternative Finder.app](https://www.techcommuters.com/best-finder-alternatives-for-mac/)*)?

#### Sleuthing

Existing information mostly concerns itself with:

- **Sort By Kind** is interchangeable with **Sort by Extension**. Not sufficiently so. [(1)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338411/sorting-files-on-extension-kind-and-then-date-in-finder-mojave) [(2)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6474178) [(3)](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-sort-by-file-extension-on-Finder-for-Mac-OS-X-Sierra)
- **Sort by Extension** is available via search. But not as a standard view. [(1)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219397/how-do-i-search-by-file-extension-in-macos-finder) [(2)](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-how-do-you-sort-by-file-extension.2241007/) [(3)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1771801)
- **Sort by Extension** is available via a third-party Finder app. [(1)](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-how-do-you-sort-by-file-extension.2241007/)
- **Sort by Extension** cannot be accomplished in Finder.app, so provide feedback [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)
  (Note: Choose macOS - Finder.app is a category in that form). [(1)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1771801) [(2)](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-how-do-you-sort-by-file-extension.2241007/)

#### Background

The **Finder.app** > **Column view** > **Sort by Kind** sort order, seen below, does not appear to sort by extension:

[image: Screenshot of a Finder window in Column view]

Comments below confirmed that **Sort by Kind** does not sort by extension, leaving the sort order sort of (*kind of?*) arbitrary in Column view.

Comment: The sorting may not be governed by the spelling of the extensions.

Comment: What are the *full file names*?  I would wager that files sorted by kind are sub-sorted alphabetically by filename and not extension.

Comment: That is unfortunate; it feels unintuitive in column view, which does not display file kind but does (or is able to) display file extension.

Comment: I have updated the question based on this information and linked to it in the question contents.

Comment: I have edited this question to encompass this new information, based on the succeeding question's flagging.